# accessing a variable reference with a list

Tags: python

I'm making a civclicker type game in python, which requires me to kill off workers when the food variable becomes negative.

Currently the method I'm thinking of using for this is using random.choice on a list, and I'm wondering if I could make the list hold a reference to a variable.

Here is my function:

```
self.maxPopulation = 0
self.workers = 0
self.farmers = 0
self.miners = 0
self.loggers = 0

def random_killer(self, amount):
    for i in range(round(amount)):
        choice = []
        choice += [self.farmers] * self.farmers + [self.miners] * self.miners + [self.loggers] * self.loggers + [self.workers] * self.workers
        chosen = random.choice(choice)
        chosen -= amount
```

So this is obviously not working as the resultant `choice` list is just an array of numbers. I've also made `self.farmers` etc. text strings and used the exec function (which didn't work), but I'm aware that using exec/eval is bad practice.

Another consideration is moving everything into a dictionary, but that will require a more general overhaul of the code - which I'm leaving for when a few other basic systems are in place.

Disregarding that - I'm curious as to whether you can actually store the reference to the `self.farmers` etc. variables in a list, as opposed to passing in numbers.

so my question is: Can you store the reference or pointer to a variable, e.g.`self.farmers`, within a list, so that the reference can be passed to another variable, `chosen`, allowing me to edit `self.farmers` dynamically.

Edit:

added a bit more detail. `self.farmers/miners/loggers/workers` is a reference to the number of people in each category.

The function above is supposed to create a list which is made by taking a reference to the above variables, and then multiplying the number of references to a variable by the number that variable represents. So in a sense if we had 5 farmers we would get a list which looks like `[self.farmers, self.farmers, self.farmers, self.farmers, self.farmers]`.

In an artificial sense each item in a list represents a person in the game, and when they are selected, that person is killed. Realistically it's just a number of references to the same variable, which is then decreased by an arbitrary amount on selection.

Comment: You have only provided an orphaned instance method, which isn't much use without context. Could you provide an example that clearly shows what you're trying to do and how your current approach fails? Are you trying to select one random person from multiple people split across multiple lists, but weighted according to the length of the lists?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - see the edit. You are close to what I mean - sorry for muddling it. I want to select one random variable (out of a possible 4 - farmers, miners, loggers and workers, each referencing a number) which are weighted according to the number they represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be easier with a dictionary. I will demonstrate it outside a class for brevity, but it could easily be an instance attribute (and you could expose the values as attributes via properties or `__getattr__`):

```
>>> import random
>>> people = {'miners': 1,
              'workers': 2,
              'farmers': 3,
              'loggers': 4}
>>> choices = [k for k, v in people.items() for _ in range(v)]
>>> choices
['loggers', 'loggers', 'loggers', 'loggers', 'workers', 'workers', 'miners', 'farmers', 'farmers', 'farmers']
>>> occupation = random.choice(choices)
>>> occupation
'loggers'
>>> people[occupation] -= 1
>>> people
{'loggers': 3, 'workers': 2, 'miners': 1, 'farmers': 3}
```

Note that you probably want to subtract `1` within your `for` loop, not `amount`.

---

To do this purely with attributes, use `getattr` and `setattr`, and store the attribute names in `choices`:

```
class Population(object):

    OCCUPATIONS = ('miners', 'workers', 'farmers', 'loggers')

    def __init__(self):
        self.miners = 1
        self.workers = 2
        self.farmers = 3
        self.loggers = 4

    def kill_random(self, n):
        for _ in range(n):
            choices = [attr for attr in self.OCCUPATIONS
                       for _ in range(getattr(self, attr))]
            occupation = random.choice(choices)
            setattr(self, occupation, getattr(self, occupation)-1)
```

In use:

```
>>> a = Population()
>>> a.kill_random(3)
>>> a.miners
0
>>> a.workers
2
>>> a.farmers
1
>>> a.loggers
4
```

Comment: That's definitely something I'm considering doing, and probably where I will head in the end. But I was wondering if it's possible to store a reference to a variable and therefore avoid using a dictionary. Out of interest.

Comment: @Scironic see the edit - basically the same but using `setattr` and `getattr`.